# C# WPF Trying to put up a Please Wait dialog

Tags: c#, wpf

In my main window, I have a button that generates a report. But the report takes about 15 seconds to build, so I simply want to put up a small dialog that asks the user to "Please wait". It then just goes away when the report window is activated. The below works except that the "Please wait" dialog only produces the shell of the window, no content.
Here is the code:

```
WD_PleaseWaitDialog _pWait = null;
private void ReportButton_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
 _pWait = new WD_PleaseWaitDialog();
 _pWait.Show();

 ReportWindow reportWindow = new ReportWindow(); // takes 15 seconds to execute
 reportWindow.Activated += closePleaseWaitWindow;
 reportWindow.Show();
} 
private void closePleaseWaitWindow( object sender, System.EventArgs e )
{
_pWait.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers. This is a great site and has provided me with lots of good info. This is what works, but it does not seem as elegant as I would like it to be:

```
private void ReportButton_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
  reportWindow = new BackUp.ReportWindow();
  StatusBarTextBox.Text = "Generating report for \"" + DestinationDirectoryTextBox.Text + "\"";
  StartWork();
} // END ReportButton_Click 

private void StartWork()
{ 
  _pWait = new WD_PleaseWaitDialog();
  _pWait.Show();

  BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  worker.DoWork += DoWork;
  worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerCompleted;
  worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void DoWork( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
{
   reportWindow.initializeReportWindow( _dailyList, _weeklyList, _monthlyList, _semiAnnualList );  
}

private void WorkerCompleted( object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
{
   _pWait.Close();
   reportWindow.Show();          
}
```

With this approach, I had to move the ReportWindow initialization out of the constructor and move it to an accessor.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your `WD_PleaseWaitDialog` gets instantiated and when you `Show()` it, it goes into `Loaded` state, but that's right before `Rendered` lifetime state.  This is when you are creating your `ReportWindow`, which takes a while to process (15 seconds according to you).  What's happening is that you're essentially blocking the main thread during that time, which prevents `WD_PleaseWaitDialog` from completing its rendering phase of its lifetime cycle.  By the time your `ReportWindow` finishes its loading, both of them get rendered, but it's so quick that you may not see the content of the `WD_PleaseWaitDialog` at all before it's closed.

There are a couple of things you can do...

- You might try working with the `ContentRendered` event of the `WD_PleaseWaitDialog` in order to proceed with the rest of the code.  But, that couples the two windows... and that's not something I personally prefer.
- You may consider using different threads.  `Task` class can greatly help you in this.  One way this may be done is to put lengthy operations in your `ReportWindow` into a `Task`:

  `Task.Run(() => { // lengthy operation here });`

When you're done with the operation, you'll need to call back into the main thread to close your `WD_PleaseWaitDialog` (since you can't handle UI operations in other threads):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    Dispatcher.Normal, new Action(_pWait.Close));
```

I'm not going to provide you the whole code unless you get really stuck.  Try to do it yourself, since I've given you plenty of information to get started.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use dispatcher.begininvoke to generate and show report

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{ /* report window */ });
```

Comment: That does not solve the issue, since all you're doing here is calling into the main thread from the main thread... (which is odd in itself).  The rendering of `WD_PleaseWaitDialog` will still get blocked by the lengthy operation in `ReportWindow`.

Comment: Issue is that waitdialog is not displayed. This solve the issue, because it will start long running process after waitdialog is rendered.

Comment: No, he did not say that the dialog is not displayed.  He said that the contents of the dialog are not displayed.  Those are completely two different things.  Your code does nothing more than if he would just create an instance of the dialog and `Show()` it, which he has done.  Do you even know what `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` does?  It does not appear so.

Comment: Well, from your answer I'm pretty sure you don't know exactly what it does. At least show some respect.

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke adds work to dispatcher queue. The difference is, that it will run in next dispatcher loop. That means after the waitdialog content is rendered.

Comment: Let's do this... test your "suggestion."  Take his code, plug in your "answer" and see what it does.

Comment: You owe me a bear ;) `var waitWindow = new Window()`
            {
                Content = "Please wait",
                Cursor = Cursors.Wait,
                SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight
            };
            waitWindow.Show();

            Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); });

Comment: I don't think so.  That's not the same code you recommended in your answer and it's still a poor way of doing things, since your code is still blocking the main thread.  Because you're blocking the thread, you won't even be able to see that `Wait` cursor until the lengthy operation finishes.

Comment: OMG, try it first before giving wise advices. It does show wait window and it does show wait cursor. It is exactly what I suggested. Instead slow `ReportWindow ctor` (or whatever is the long running report generation) I just used `Thread.Sleep()`

Of course it is blocking ui thread. Since he has report generation coupled with UI, it cannot be easily done in background thread. Moreover, UI does not need to stay responsive in this case. All he was asking for was wait dialog which I did.

Comment: I did try it. It blocks the main thread and the wait cursor does not appear until after the lengthy operation is over, so your code can't even guarantee predicted behavior for every user.  Furthermore, this code is different from your original answer. Using `Task` it can be done very easily and without blocking threads, so you should look into those. This conversation is dragging on and you're obviously not getting it, so I'm just going to end this here.